# Why does Samsung company name means "Three stars" and not "Three castle"?

Tags: translation, meaning, korean-to-english

From Wikipedia: "The Samsung Group (Korean: 삼성)"

I went to Google Translate and pasted the two words: 
삼 = three  
성 = castle (and other options, none of them being star)

If I paste them together, 삼성, it just says Samsung.

The only place 성 was related to star was here:  별 성; byeol seong (from wiki page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seong)

So, why does Samsung company name means "Three stars" and not "Three castles"?

Comment: That 별 성 is the 성 in 삼성三星.

Comment: You want a real puzzler: Why is the letter "A" in their _current_ logo a pair of slacks?!? (It totally is! Look closely one day, and you'll never be able to un-see it. I call it the "pants logo".)

Comment: The name was originally written in Hanja that works the same way Japanese Kanji does; for example the Japanese company name Nintendo is written as `任天堂`(임천당) and it means "a house whose fate is left to heaven".

Comment: If I tell you I've met three "stars", how do you know I mean "famous people" and not three astronomical balls of fusion?  Context.

Comment: You are making the basic error of assuming that Wikipedia is reliable https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Wikipedia_is_not_a_reliable_source

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you search for "ant" in a small English dictionary, you will only find about the insect.  But "Antarctica" is not ant's Arctic, it's "anti-Arctica", i.e., something that's the opposite side of the Arctic.  In fact "ant(i)-" is a very common English prefix, even though it's normally not used as an word by itself.

Many Korean words are made of Hanja (Chinese characters) - 星(별 성) is one of them, and a very common one.  You won't find the letter used by itself, but it shows up in tons of words whose meaning are related to stars.

Edit: Also, if you're wondering "but how do we know the 성 in 삼성 is 'star' and not some other hanja?"  That's a fair question - and the answer is that we know because 삼성 literally used to write its name as 三星, with its brand logo prominently showing three stars.  Search "samsung old logo" in Google, for example.

Answer (score 4):

「城」 (*재* **성**, *castle*) and 「星」 (*별* **성**, *star*) are homophones, but the company started off literally as 「株式會社　**三星**商會」 (주식회사 **삼성**상회, *Samsung Trading [Kabushiki-gaisha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kabushiki_gaisha)*). 「三星」 means *three stars*.

Here's a photo of their old standing building, prominently displaying their original name:

#### 株式會社　三星商會

[image: Old Samsung building]

---

> The only place 성 was related to star was here: 별 성; byeol seong (from wiki page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seong)

*별* **성** is in the format of an 音訓 (음훈) dictionary gloss for the character 「星」, where

- 「별」 is the 訓讀 (훈독, *meaning-reading*, i.e. native Korean translation) of 「星」.
- 「성」 is the 音讀 (음독, *sound-reading*, i.e. Korean sound derived from [Middle Chinese](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Middle_Chinese)).

「별」 means *star*, and this is the *meaning-reading* given to the character 「星」, as opposed to the *meaning-reading* 「재」 given to 「城」 (*castle*). This is how the characters 「星」 and 「城」 are distinguished, even though both are pronounced (i.e., have a *sound-reading* of) 「성」.

See also [What is 훈음 in a layman's words?](https://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/5546/what-is-%ed%9b%88%ec%9d%8c-in-a-laymans-words/5548).

Comment: That... is an awesomely tiny structure to have ever housed any part of (what became) the corporate behemoth that is 21st Century Samsung! 

Answer (score 2):

Because 성 means star

From wikipedia:

Samsung native name: 삼성 (三星)

星 = 성 = [star](https://hanja.dict.naver.com/hanja?q=%E6%98%9F)